# angularjs custom directive not working

Tags: angularjs, directive

I added my custom attribute to my application like this

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive('orientable', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      element.bind("load", function (e) {
        console.log('test');
        /* my code is here*/

      });

    }
  }
});
```

Add using this in my view like this

```
<div class="xyz" orientable></div>
```

but it is not calling link function, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: does the browser console show any errors? did you attempt to debug?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: are you sure your app is running? Do you have `ng-app` somewhere in your html?

Comment: here is the link for jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b695p/

Comment: what is objective? `div` won't trigger a `load` event. Demo breaks without proper resources also

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't work.

Don't know what you are trying to do, but [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/b695p/1/) works.

Just do what you want on `link` function.

Answer (score 0):

as lante said, your fiddle is broken. It isn't loading angular or its dependecies (cookies and animation). On another note, there is no `load` for a div. Just move your log out of the `element.bind...`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope)
{
    //controller logic
}]);

myApp.directive('orientable',function () {       
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {   
            console.log('yahan');               
            element.addClass("vertical");             
        }
    }
});
```

You also had `restrict: 'E'` which is element name as in `<orientable></orientable>`

You have it as an attribute so you need to change the `restrict` to `A`

You can do `restrict: 'EA'` and have the ability to use either method (attribute or element name).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem. Finally I got to know that we need to load "orientable" as DI module for ng-app. We need to add this "orientable".